# Background image is not displaying in rendered mode

Tags: 3d-view, tracking

how to make background image sequence displayed in render mode in the 3D view? I made a 3D tracking and I want to see the original video as a background.

This is what i mean: 
In "material mode" I can see the background

[image]

But not in "render mode":

[image]

Comment: Make sure under *Render Settings > Film* Transparent is not checked. Also make sure you are not in Orthographic view.

Comment: WHat method are you using to display background image?

Comment: I added a more detailed description with illustrations

Comment: It looks to me like you are tracking some video. Is that what you want to see in the background? If so you will not get that in the preview render in the 3D view. If you have the compositor already set up doing a full render `F 12` will add the video as the background.

Comment: @David yes, this is 3d tracking. OK, I understand, thank you!

Comment: @MaximVelichkin, please update your question accordingly. The fact you want a video in the background is important for us to answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Polosson Ok, no prob.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the Properties window on the *Scene* Tab under the *Film* section check the transparent box:

[image]

Otherwise your background will be the color set in the Properties->World->Surface settings.

Comment: Note that this works only in viewport rendering

Answer (score 5):

I have Blender 2.76b  Here goes! Images below to match settings.

1. You have to set up a simple Node - No choice!!
   Copy settings
2. Set Sky to Transparent:  Scene
3. World View to Paper Sky: World
4. Shadows From Lighting Need Planes to collect and show only Shadow in Render
   "Color"

5.
In 3D view - Hit "N" Go down to "Background Images" "Check mark" the box and load the background you want.

6. Go back to "Nodes" Click on the "IMAGE" Node - The Envelope on the left bottom of that Node and select the loaded image you just loaded in step 5.
         "SEE LAST LITTLE IMAGE FOR PROPER PLACE TO CLICK!"

[image: Main Idea]

7. Adding Shadows "Bonus"  Add Planes and Match settings in Color Tab.
   Example - look close for shadows on the wall...  For better effects, adjust your light power and Samples/Soft effects[image]

Comment: I was only given two images to get this info out.  Sorry for the continuity issues.

Comment: Hey Bob, welcome to BSE! Nice answer. For three images where you are just showing settings in the properties window, please crop it to just what is needed. That will make much it easier to see what the correct setting should be.

Answer (score 2):

you must go under properties(default on the right)/texture/world texture then create world texture and set the world texture to image or movie. Then you must scroll down to influence and check horizan.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I use cycles render, as i see, texture of the world there can be set in the "world" panel (also on the right), but when I set the image texture there, instead of the image I see gray-green screen in the background. How to adjust the texture of the world in cycles render?