# Background movie clip does not show up in render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

I did some tracking in Adobe AE and then ran a script to import it into Blender. I set a background image in the N menu, but I can only see it in the viewport, I can't see it when I render. Any help would be appreciated. Blender 2.79b, cycles render.
[image: no background, render]

Comment: The background images you setup in the viewport settings are only for reference in the viewport while modelling. [This answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67925/935) should provide your answer.

Answer (score 0):

In Blender render its under solve>Scene Setup (in the movie clip editor