# How can I add background to rendered image

Tags: rendering

I have just made my render but I cannot see the background in my Rendered Image. I have already added it to the "camera perspective" but still cannot see it in the rendered image. Please help me because I really want my render to be perfect...

Comment: related, possible duplicates: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38452/cycles-not-rendering-movie-clip-used-as-background/38464#38464 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50988/how-do-you-work-with-a-background-image-in-3d-view-and-then-also-include-that-im

Comment: Also related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/38333/background-image-shows-in-front-of-3d-objects-not-behind-them and http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-to-composite-in-a-background-picture/5804#5804 and maybe http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28772/background-image-is-not-displaying-in-rendered-mode/45033#45033

Answer (score 3):

You can  create plane and use this recipe with texture you like it works perfectly every time

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you use Cycles for rendering you can add a background after having finished rendering using the compositor. You'll need to render with a transparent background. To do so you have to check 'Transparent' in the Film settings of the render tab.

[image: Check this for a transparent background]

For compositing you can follow the steps explained in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5802/how-to-composite-in-a-background-picture?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this. 
But the simplest way is to use the "import_images_as_planes"  addon.

Just enable it from the preferences. 
Then go to the import >Import images as planes.. And choose your BG image.

This week bring in a plane into your scene with the image perfectly mapped onto it. 
Now you can change the material and position etc to get the  best effect you need. 
Hope this helps.